# How to filter a list by multiple predicates in one pass?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I filter a list by a few predicates, e.g.

```
val xs = List(1, 0, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, 5, 0)
val pred1: Int => Boolean = _ > 0
val pred2: Int => Boolean = _ < 0
val pred3: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0

val xs1 = xs.filter(pred1) // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
val xs2 = xs.filter(pred2) // List(-1, -6)
val xs3 = xs.filter(pred3) // List(0, 2, 4, -6, 0)
```

How to filter a list by all these predicates in one pass only ?

```
def filterByFew(xs: List[Int], preds: List[Int => Boolean]): List[List[Int]] = ???
```

`filterByFew(xs, List(pred1, pred2, pred3))` should return
   `List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5), List(-1, -6), List(0, 2, 4, -6, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Andrey Tyukin's answer does not address the "in one pass" aspect of the question. If the order of elements don't have to be preserved, then I think following implementation will be reasonably efficient:

```
def filterByFew[A](xs: Traversable[A], preds: List[A => Boolean]): List[List[A]] = {
  xs.foldLeft(List.fill(preds.size)(List.empty[A]))((acc, el) => {
    acc.zip(preds).map({
      case (l, p) => if (p(el)) el :: l else l
    })
  })
}
```

If the order has to be preserved the simple solution is reverse all the inner list at the end of `filterByFew` but if filters are not very selective it is effectively iterating over the whole collection multiple times. The other solution would be something like this:

```
def filterByFew2[A](xs: Traversable[A], preds: List[A => Boolean]): List[Traversable[A]] = {
  val builders = xs.foldLeft(List.fill(preds.size)(xs.companion.newBuilder[A]))((acc, el) => {
    acc.zip(preds).foreach({
      case (b, p) => if (p(el)) b += el
    })
    acc
  })
  builders.map(b => b.result())
}
```

It is less FP but better for performance. Actually this is similar to how `filter` is implemented inside the standard library.

A simple test to ensure that this works as claimed is something like this:

```
def test(): Unit = {
  val xs0 = List(1, 0, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, 5, 0)
  val xs = xs0.view.map(x => {
    println(s"accessing $x")
    x
  })
  val pred1: Int => Boolean = _ > 0
  val pred2: Int => Boolean = _ < 0
  val pred3: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0
  val preds = List(pred1, pred2, pred3)
  val res = preds.map(xs.filter)
  println(res)
  println("---------------")
  println(filterByFew(xs, preds))
  println("---------------")
  println(filterByFew2(xs, preds))

}
```

`view` is lazy method so we'll log every access to the underlying collection. It is easy to see that the Andrey's code access each element 3 times while my solutions do it only once.

Comment: It now does address it, I wrote out a filter-with-multiple-predicates implementation that should work on any iterator.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I believe that using the builder from the `xs` is better than always creating `List` but this is probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the `fold` solution.

Comment: @SergGr Yeah, sure, one could also throw in a CanBuildFrom, for good measure, to tie the collection type of the result to the type of the input... I still prefer the one-liner, until a profiler tells me to do otherwise. This answer somehow conflates commenting on other answers with the actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

**One-liner answer that still traverses the collection multiple times:**

```
List(pred1, pred2, pred3).map(xs.filter)
```

as method:

```
def filterByFew(xs: List[Int], preds: List[Int => Boolean]): List[List[Int]] = 
  preds.map(xs.filter)
```

It works with streams in pretty much the same way:

```
val p1 = (x: Int) => x % 2 == 0
val p2 = (x: Int) => x % 3 == 0

val preds = List(p1, p2)
val str = Stream.from(0)

val filteredStreams = preds.map(str.filter)
filteredStreams foreach { s => println(s.take(10).toList) }

// Output:
// List(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18)
// List(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27)
```

but don't try it in the REPL: the REPL hangs itself why trying to display the intermediate results.

---

**Traversing the collection once**

If you really cannot afford traversing the collection multiple times, then I don't see any efficient workarounds, the simplest thing would seem to be to reimplement `filter`, but with multiple mutable builders:

```
def filterByMultiple[A](
  it: Iterator[A],
  preds: List[A => Boolean]
): List[List[A]] = {
  val n = preds.size
  val predsArr = preds.toArray
  val builders = Array.fill(n){
    new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[A]
  }
  for (a <- it) {
    for (j <- 0 until n) {
      if (predsArr(j)(a)) {
        builders(j) += a
      }
    }
  }
  builders.map(_.result)(collection.breakOut)
}


filterByMultiple((0 to 30).iterator, preds) foreach println
// Output:
// List(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30)
// List(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)
```

---

**If you came here from a Google-search, you probably wanted something else:**

AND-ing multiple predicates:

```
def filterByAnd(xs: List[Int], preds: List[Int => Boolean]) = 
  xs.filter(x => preds.forall(p => p(x)))
```

OR-ing multiple predicates:

```
def filterByOr(xs: List[Int], preds: List[Int => Boolean]) = 
  xs.filter(x => preds.exists(p => p(x)))
```

Comment: You are calling `filter` on `xs` three times, so it is not really "one pass". And how can this work if `xs` is a stream?

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure what you mean by "one pass" then. It's supposed to produce three *separate* lists, each list *filtered* by a different predicate, so, inevitably, it will invoke `filter` three times, because a single invocation of `filter` can produce at most one list; What would be the problem of doing the same with streams?

Comment: @Tim Maybe this approach would be a little bit more problematic with `Iterator`s that don't cache the previously produced values, but that was not part of the question.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, assume `xs` has one billion elements. In such case just accessing them all 3 times is a source of inefficiency. For me "_in one pass only_" clearly means that we want to access each element in the collection only once. And your code does not achieve that. "in one pass" is definitely different from "in one line of code"

Comment: Thank you guys for the helpful discussion. Now I understand better what I wanted :)

Comment: @Michael I've completely lost track, and no longer know what you wanted. Hope you can recycle something from all this stuff ;P

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Sure. Thanks.